# How to extract the value of an apparently non-standard html tag in r

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I have the following summarized html code (html_file.html).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="listing-wrapper__content">
<section class="card__amenities ">
<p class="l-text l-u-color-neutral-28 l-text--variant-body-small l-text--weight-regular card__amenity" itemprop="floorSize"><span data-testid="l-icon" role="document" aria-label="Tamanho do imóvel" class="l-icon l-u-color-undefined"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">...</svg></span> 94 - 100 m² </p>
<p class="l-text l-u-color-neutral-28 l-text--variant-body-small l-text--weight-regular card__amenity" itemprop="numberOfRooms"><span data-testid="l-icon" role="document" aria-label="Quantidade de quartos" class="l-icon l-u-color-undefined"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">...</svg></span> 3 </p>
<p class="l-text l-u-color-neutral-28 l-text--variant-body-small l-text--weight-regular card__amenity" itemprop="numberOfBathroomsTotal"<span data-testid="l-icon" role="document" aria-label="Quantidade de banheiros" class="l-icon l-u-color-undefined"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">...</svg></span>3</p>
<p class="l-text l-u-color-neutral-28 l-text--variant-body-small l-text--weight-regular card__amenity"><span data-testid="l-icon" role="document" aria-label="Quantidade de vagas de garagem" class="l-icon l-u-color-undefined"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><...</svg></span>2</p>
</section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I managed to extract the first three elements. For example:

```r
library(rvest)
pagee <- read_html("html_file.html") 
nofrooms <- html_elements(pagee, ".listing-wrapper__content")%>%html_nodes("[itemprop='numberOfRooms']")%>%html_text()
nofrooms
```

Output is

```r
" 3 "
```

The problem is in the **last p tag**. There is apparently no standard for me to be able to extract information from such a tag. I have tried the following without success:

```r
nofgarage <- html_elements(pagee, ".listing-wrapper__content")%>%html_nodes("[aria-label='Quantidade de vagas de garagem']")%>%html_text()
nofgarage
```

Output is

```r
""
```

The result is empty as expected, as the value I want to extract is not between the span tags.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I can't find `.listing-wrapper__content` in your example code. Can you provide a reproducible example? And also your desired output.

Comment: It is a long and complex page. But I'll try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears the that there is mostly 4 amenities, one could use `xml_child()` function from xml2 to select the that amenity.
In this case there are a few listing that is missing the 4th amenity so we need to filter before attempting to extract.
See comments below.

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/venda/apartamentos/ms+campo-grande/?transacao=venda&onde=,Mato%20Grosso%20do%20Sul,Campo%20Grande,,,,,city,BR%3EMato%20Grosso%20do%20Sul%3ENULL%3ECampo%20Grande,-20.464852,-54.621848,&tipos=apartamento_residencial&pagina=1"

#read page
pagee <- read_html(url)

#get the amentities section from each listing
sections <- html_elements(pagee, "section.card__amenities ")
#sections %>% html_elements("p") %>% html_text()

#create an empty vector
garages <- vector("numeric", length=length(sections))

#retrieve the 4 node value - not all apartments have a 4 values thus the need to filter
garages[xml_length(sections)==4] <- sapply(sections[xml_length(sections)==4], function(node) 
                                   {xml_child(node, 4) %>% html_text()})

#answer the final vector
garages
# [1] "2" "4" "1" "1" "1" "1" "0" "2" "2" "2" "3" "1" "1" "1" "0"
```

Comment: Perfect!!!! Thank's very much!!!Note: Need to edit where there is "section" for "sections".

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your example code and assuming that you only want to extract the number in the end, we could use a workaround with the `xpath` argument and exclude everything inside the `<svg>` tag and then `purrr::discard` all empty strings:

```r
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

html |> 
  read_html(html) |> 
  html_elements("p") |>
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[not(name()="svg")]/text()') |> 
  html_text(trim=TRUE) |> 
  purrr::discard(\(x) x == "")
#> [1] "94 - 100 m²" "3"           "3"           "2"
```

Data from OP

```r
html <- '<section class="card__amenities ">
<p class="l-text l-u-color-neutral-28 l-text--variant-body-small l-text--weight-regular card__amenity" itemprop="floorSize"><span data-testid="l-icon" role="document" aria-label="Tamanho do imóvel" class="l-icon l-u-color-undefined"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">...</svg></span> 94 - 100 m² </p>
<p class="l-text l-u-color-neutral-28 l-text--variant-body-small l-text--weight-regular card__amenity" itemprop="numberOfRooms"><span data-testid="l-icon" role="document" aria-label="Quantidade de quartos" class="l-icon l-u-color-undefined"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">...</svg></span> 3 </p>
<p class="l-text l-u-color-neutral-28 l-text--variant-body-small l-text--weight-regular card__amenity" itemprop="numberOfBathroomsTotal"<span data-testid="l-icon" role="document" aria-label="Quantidade de banheiros" class="l-icon l-u-color-undefined"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">...</svg></span>3</p>
<p class="l-text l-u-color-neutral-28 l-text--variant-body-small l-text--weight-regular card__amenity"><span data-testid="l-icon" role="document" aria-label="Quantidade de vagas de garagem" class="l-icon l-u-color-undefined"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><...</svg></span>2</p>
</section>'
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi TimTeaFan. Thank you for your help. The presented solution is not feasible for the case of several divs, as some contain the target value, others do not. Therefore, trying some solution based on object indexing will not work. Here's the page I'm scraping: "https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/venda/apartamentos/ms+campo-grande/?pagina=1". Thanks again.